# Turn off RuboCop rule that favours 'unless' over if for negative conditions

Tags: ruby, if-statement, rubocop, unless

If I write

```
if !File.exists('file_path')
   # create file
end
```

I see a RuboCop warning:

```
 Favour `unless` over `if` for negative conditions
```

Unfortunately, using `unless` in this type of context at some point leads to cognitive confusion for me. I am not the only one, please see this [issue](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide/issues/329).

So what do I put in my `.rubcopy.yml` file to turn this cop off?

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/NegatedIf

Comment: In English we would generally say "unless the File exists" rather than "If not the File exists"; however, I have heard your objection from quite a few non-native English speakers. For instance "wenn nicht" in German has the same cognitive meaning as "unless" in English but the literal translation is actually "if not", so in German "wenn nicht die Datei existiert" is "If the File does not exist" or "If not the File exists".

Comment: The Rubocop rule should be rewritten to **always use `if`, not `unless`**. This way, it is easier to maintain and extend complex conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the following in your `.rubocop.yml` config file:

```
Style/NegatedIf:
  Enabled: false
```

To disable the following Rubocop warning:

```
Favour `unless` over `if` for negative conditions
```